# Is my dwarf cavendish "main" stem dead?

Tags: houseplants

I recently purchased a Musa dwarf cavendish. I repotted into a slightly larger pot. The plant within the next few days wilted and never recovered. I am new to houseplants and I believe it may be due to repotting shock. The soil was wet when I repotted and I have not watered again since

The plant is now turned mostly yellow and brown, with a small amount of green left on a new leaf at the top.
Luckily however there is a new shoot and leaves growing which looks perfectly healthy.

Can I / Should I now cut away the dead leaves? Can I remove the larger stem completely?  I don't know it certainly dead, however, it just looks worse each day. Should I remove the dying stem completely or is there still hope?

Will cutting away the dead/dying stem effect the smaller healthy one?

See pics below :

[image]

[image]